# Why does this density exceed 1?

Tags: r

Why does the density on the y axis sometimes have values greater than 1 if the curve is representing density?

See the example below where I use R's density() function to plot a density curve.

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000, 1, 0.01)))
```

[image: Density curve]

Comment: Include reproducible examples (dput is your friend).

Comment: Hmmm... `density` always plots density, as far as I know, not frequency... can you show an example of it plotting frequency?

Comment: I have attached my example. I mean density not hist. Thanks

Comment: @user22062: I think nobody has a problem with `density` plotting density... but in what case do you get frequency? On a side note, your example is not reproducible, as mydataset is not shown...

Comment: This should *NOT* have been closed as off topic - the underlying issue is clearly a statistical misunderstanding, but the OP is perhaps too confused to realize that. Instead this should be closed as a *duplicate*.

Comment: It also is a statistical issue that stackoverflow screws up over (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368223/ggplot2-multi-group-histogram-with-in-group-proportions-rather-than-frequency) and over (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064080/plot-relative-frequencies-with-dodged-bar-plots-in-ggplot2).

Comment: user22062 - to see that this problem has *nothing* to do with R, and is in fact proper behavior of a density function, compute the height of a uniform density on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ in that range; for more detail, check out @whuber's answer at the link I gave above to the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Corrected, @Glen_b! Thanks for the pointer. (I initially closed a different version of this post.)